# How to display a textbox if "others" option from checkbox group is checked

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, checkbox

I want to display a text box using JavaScript when the "Other" option is checked from a group of checkboxes. I'm using razor pages with asp.net core 2.2

I'm using the following script but it is not working.

```
   function onSelectChange() {
        var sel = document.getElementById('QuestionOptionId');
        var strUser = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text; 


       if (strUser.startsWith('Other'))
                document.getElementById('textBox').disabled = false;          

       else
            document.getElementById('textBox').disabled = true;  
    }
</script>
```

Fruits.cshtml ( razor page view file)

```
        @foreach (var option in Model.QuestionOptions)
        {
            <input type="checkbox"  asp-for="QuestionOptionId"   id ="QuestionOptionId"  value ="@option.Value" onclick="onSelectChange()" />  @option.Text<br />              
        }
```

QuestionOptions is a selectList:

```
Value=1 Text= Apple, 
Value=2 Text= Kiwi, 
Value=3 Text =Other
```

whenever the user checks the checkbox for "Other", it should display a textbox.
What am I doing wrong here? I have read so many other answers but not able to figure out this one.

**Update-1**

I don't know why the post is not showing the textbox control...
I'm pasting it here again, it is outside the foreach loop. I have removed the angle brackets as I think it is mixing with formatting.

input type="text" id="textBox" name="response" disabled="disabled"

Comment: I don't see the textBox control anywhere in your code. You need to create the textBox control in Fruits.cshtml.

Comment: Your JS code is applied to a dropdown list and the id in not unique in you view.Do you use a `<select>`?Could you show your form code and QuestionOptionId defined in pagemodel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following modification in the view and the javascript:

Add the label outside the input

```
@foreach (var option in Model.QuestionOptions)
{
   <Lable>
       <input type="checkbox" asp-for="QuestionOptionId" id="QuestionOptionId"  value="@option.Value"  /> @option.Text
   </Lable>
   <br />
}
<div>
    <input type="text" id="textbox" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
```

Use `$(this).parent().text().trim()` to get the text

```
$('input:checkbox').on('click', function () {
            if ($(this).parent().text().trim() === "Other") {
                $('#textbox').removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        });
```

**Update**

If you want to hide the text box and hide the textbox when you uncheck the "other option , firstly you could change the `disabled` attribute to `hidden` ,and then determine if the text box contains `hidden` attribute in js like below :

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" hidden />

if ($(this).parent().text().trim() === "Other")
   {
       if ($('#textbox').is(':hidden')) {
           $('#textbox').removeAttr("hidden");
        }
        else {
             $('#textbox').attr("hidden", "hidden");
             }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working. But how to disable the textbox when I uncheck the "other option. Once I check it the text box gets enabled but on unchecking the checkbox it is not getting disabled. also, how do I hide it instead of disabling it?

Comment: @Aditi  If you find my workaround works , could you mark my reply as an answer? This will help others who have the same doubts to find the answer quickly .Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Full disclosure: I have never used Razor pages or asp.net

I'm having a hard time following how your javascript is detecting whether the other option is checked.  It seems like your Fruits.cshtml is going to generate three separate inputs with the same "QuestionOptionId" id.

Also, your Fruits.cshtml snipped doesn't include the code for the textbox you'd like to enable, though I'm assuming you have a textbox with id "textBox" in the compiled HTML that you'd like to enable.

I would change your script out for this:

```
function onSelectChange(element) {
  if (element === element.parentNode.querySelector(".other")) {
    console.dir(element);
    if (element.checked) {
      document.getElementById("textBox").disabled = false;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("textBox").disabled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

You'll need to add the "other" class to your applicable "Other" input checkbox.  You'll also need to change your Fruits.cshtml snippet so that the "onclick" function also passes the applicable element into the script.

```
@foreach (var option in Model.QuestionOptions)
{
    <input type="checkbox"  asp-for="QuestionOptionId"   id ="QuestionOptionId"  value ="@option.Value" onclick="onSelectChange(this)" />  @option.Text<br />              
}
```

Here's a working example of the compiled code: https://codepen.io/bourn404/pen/yWVLdx

Comment: Yes, the foreach loop is generating the three options. I cannot use the class="other" as for that I have to mention each checkbox in a separate tag. I want to generate the checkbox options through foreach-loop which is fetching it from database.